# Can I add collaborators to my chrome extension? like multi-admin for the same extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension on Chrome store under my account, and wondering if I can add another admin as well who will be working with me and make some modifications on the extension? Is there anyway to do so? (I don't really want to give him my Chrome store credentials, as I have other extension as well under my account and I don't want him to access all of them).

Thanks and really appreciate if somebody provide me with an answer!

Comment: You can try to set up a Group, according to [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#set-up-group-publishing), but it doesn't work on an extension basis, I think.

Comment: Just checked again, you can put individual items (extensions) in the group, so this might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks! it works. however, now I'm stuck in transferring items from my personal account to the group I created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up publishing group for the items you want to have collaborative admin rights, according to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#set-up-group-publishing).

Comment: Thanks again! this is the link of my new related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61820673/how-to-move-existing-items-chrome-extension-from-my-personal-account-to-a-grou . Hope you could help as well :/