# How to move existing items (Chrome extension) from my personal account to a Group Publisher account?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension in my personal account, and I already created a Group Publisher account, and now I want to move the extension from my personal account to the Group publisher account I've created.

I already read this document: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#move-existing-items-to-a-group-publisher-account

I was able to create and setup the Group publisher, but the problem now is that I can't see the Transfer existing item(s) option (that's supposed to be next to Add New Item button, according to the documentation). and I'm stuck there!

Any recommendation?[image: This is what my Group Publisher Account dashboard looks like]

Comment: Never tried Group Publishing, but here are 2 ideas: 1) check you have the group selected in the publisher dropdown (the one you hid in the picture), and 2) try in the old developer dashboard: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard instead of the new one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole/

Comment: Yes it is the group publisher account that I selected, and regarding the old version of the dashboard, it redirects me automatically to the new one! There should be a way, I might contact google support as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is my first answer here, and I am glad to be helpful to you.

«Transfer existing item(s)» option is not available in new version of Developer Dashboard, which you are using.

In lower left-corner find Feedback window, press «Show more» and click «Opt out».

You will be redirected to older version of Dashboard, when the needed button is available.

Comment: WOW it finally works! Thank you so much, really appreciate it !!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the option "transfer to group publisher" in the kebab menu on the right of the "Submit for review" button now.

[image: Screenshot showing the three dots menu button on the right of the toolbar of an Google Chrome Extension Dashboard, showing a dropdown with the options Preview, Unpublish and Transfer to group publisher]

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem and solved by another way.

First, click the expand menu on the left top corner, choose 「Account」

scroll to the bottom, u will see group publisher config in Management block, after configuring it, back to the extension detail page,

Comment: click "Transfer to group publisher", there will be an option which is u selected just now.